# how to launch firefox 50.0.2 version on selenium 2.44.0 without geckodriver on suse 12

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am not able to open Firefox 50.0.2 version with python 2.44.0 selenium on suse 12 OS.

Please any one can help me how to open fire fox without " geckodriver " driver.

Regards,
Sriram

Comment: Answer from Jim Evans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916650/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-marionette-firefoxdriver-instead-of-the-old-selen/38917100#38917100

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. As of Firefox 47 you need the *geckodriver* binary to manage the browser from Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: Is it possible to downgrade Firefox version offline in SUSE Linux OS.